# Add field to report type with Apex or Salesforce REST API

Tags: apex, apexrest

I have a lot of custom report types (100+), adding a new/existing field to the report types is a tedious and manual process. I am looking for a Salesforce REST API or APEX snippet for doing the same.

Comment: For new fields there is setting you can enable to allow them to automatically get added to report type.
In report and dashboard setting "Select Auto add new custom fields to custom report type layouts".
For existing fields if same set of fields are to be added in multiple report types, I am thinking why not try metadata api

Comment: @elijah thanks, I am looking for metadata API, I am not finding any references.

Comment: I meant more in terms of reducing effort as if you retrieve one of custom report types, you can add your xml (with same tags) then deploy it. 
If same fields are to be added in multiple report types , you would just create it once and re-use it (thinking out loud)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you were referring to https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi.

The above can help you query for custom report types.